need equivalent for hibernate 4.2.21.final method name : String[] generateSchemaCreationScript(Dialect dialect) for Hibernate 5.6.15.Final version
I'm trying to upgrade hibernate version of my project from 4.2.21.final to Hibernate 5.6.15.Final version.
In one of the class there is this method:: String[] script = config.generateSchemaCreationScript(new PontisMySqlDialect());  of org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.class of Hibernate 4.2.21.Final and I'm getting error on it as its not present in the newer version of Hibernate(5.6.15) which I'm currently trying to upgrade to.
I tried search on the web along with chat GPT and other AI tools but none of them seems to be helping in resolving my issue.
I even tried to replicate the method implementation from its older version (hibernate 4.2.21.final) but its getting too complex to understand.
What I want is an equivalent of this method for my newer hibernate version (5.6.15.final) or to do such thing is there a new functionality and how to implement that exactly.
One approach I tried is below, but not sure if it will work or not::
public static String[] generateSchemaCreationScript(Dialect dialect) {
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder registryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
registryBuilder.applySetting("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
StandardServiceRegistry registry = registryBuilder.configure().build();
try {
MetadataSources metadataSources = new MetadataSources(registry);
Metadata metadata = metadataSources.buildMetadata();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
SchemaExport schemaExport = new SchemaExport();
schemaExport.setDelimiter(";");
schemaExport.setFormat(true);
schemaExport.setOutputFile(null);
schemaExport.create(EnumSet.of(TargetType.DATABASE), metadata);
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
return writer.toString().split("\n");
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
return new String[0];
}
}

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
